# How to display data in DataGrid with Silverlight

Tags: sql, sql-server, silverlight, datagrid

I want to run a SQL Query like

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1 WHERE userID.table1 = userID.table2
```

I want the output to go to the a DataGrid.

I am using SQL Server 2012.
This is a Silverlight 5 application using the "Business Application" template.

---

Here is my code from my C# WinForm App. I am trying to port to Silverlight

```
    public SqlConnection ConnectionStateToSQLServer()
    {
        //string source = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=catalog_skull_primary;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        //databaseConnectionstring = source;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionstring);
            conn.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Connection Test Successful");
            connection = conn;
            conn.Close();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: and what is your problem? You said what you want, but what you have done so far?

Comment: i've tried many things and I can't get it to work. I used the same connection strings as I would for any C# application by going to connectionstrings.com

Comment: Are you using WCF services for getting datas fom database? Because, System.Data is not supported in Silverlight. Show some parts of your code also.

Comment: Well I have no working code that is able to get the data out of my database. That's why I am stuck. My C# app used System.Data and System.